Android Deep Linking: How to programmatically trigger LINE app user search with specific ID
I'm developing an Android app that needs to deep link into the LINE messaging app to search for specific users.
Current implementation:
val searchIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply {
    data = Uri.parse("https://line.me/R/nv/addFriends")
    `package` = "jp.naver.line.android"
    addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
}
startActivity(searchIntent)

This successfully opens LINE's Add Friends screen, but I need to automatically trigger the search with a specific ID.
What I've tried:

Direct profile URL:

Uri.parse("https://line.me/R/ti/p/%40${encodedId}")


Search endpoint with parameters:

Uri.parse("https://line.me/R/nv/searchId")
putExtra("id", searchId)


Recommended format from LINE docs:

Uri.parse("https://line.me/R/ti/p/%40userid%C2%A0and%C2%A0https://line.me/R/nv/recommendOA/%40userid")

All attempts either:

Show "check whether link is correct" error
Open LINE but don't trigger search
Open wrong screen

Environment:

Android 14
LINE app latest version
Testing on physical device

Is there a correct URL scheme or intent extra to programmatically trigger LINE's user search?

No, the LINE docs recommend using "https://line.me/R/ti/p/%40userid and https://line.me/R/nv/recommendOA/%40userid", depending on what you need. Not "https://line.me/R/ti/p/%40userid%C2%A0and%C2%A0https://line.me/R/nv/recommendOA/%40userid"
